# Assigning random starting points

Tags: java

So I am trying to assign random starting points for an object.

```
    int x = random.nextInt(INIT_WIDTH) - radius;
    int y = random.nextInt(INIT_HEIGHT) - radius;
```

x and y are the starting points for the object and INIT_WIDTH and HEIGHT are the width and height. When I ran the program, the anchor point coordinates appear to be the same, which is the upper-left part of the frame. I really don't know what I did wrong?

Comment: what is random and how does nextInt work? Are you using a specific library? Those aren't STL functions.

Comment: @PeterT So it is - corrected.

Comment: Are you saying that when you run this, that x and y are both assigned the value 0?  What are INIT_WIDTH and INIT_HEIGHT and what are their values?

Comment: You should also spare a thought to the distribution you want of random points.

Generally (with games programming at least) you want multiple objects "randomly spread" rather then "randomly placed" So it depends what you wanna do.

Comment: INIT_WIDTH and HEIGHT are the width and height (of what? the canvas or the object) assuming canvas, what is radius expected to be? half the width? radius usually is only used on circles afaik.